# Is there any way to store data every 5 second in new text file?

Tags: python, datetime, time, python-datetime

I have created a program which is reading the sensor data. As per my usecase i have to store the readings in a text file every 5 seconds with new file names example: file1, file2, file3 and so on until i stop the program using keyboard. Can anyone guide me to accomplish this task?

```
import sys
import time
import board
import digitalio
import busio
import csv
import adafruit_lis3dh
from datetime import datetime, timezone
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
int1 = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D6)  # Set this to the correct pin for the interrupt!
lis3dh = adafruit_lis3dh.LIS3DH_I2C(i2c, int1=int1)
lis3dh.range = adafruit_lis3dh.RANGE_2_G



with open("/media/pi/D427-7B2E/test.txt", 'w') as f:
  sys.stdout = f


  while True:
      ti = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000)
      x, y, z = lis3dh.acceleration
      print('{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(ti,x / 9.806, y / 9.806, z / 9.806))
      time.sleep(0.001)
      pass
```

Comment: Since the `while` loop is sleeping for `0.001` second, you can certainly write a counter to track how many times it ran, so your code write to the file every time the counter hits 5000 (remember to reset it). Better way is to count how long your code last logged and execute the statement to write to a file then when then time limit passed 5 seconds (and reset that counter)

Comment: the while loop is running forever

Comment: Yes, inside the while loop, you will need to add the logic to track either the counter or the time.

Comment: can you share a example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try logging?
have a look on TimedRotatingFileHandler may be this could help

Can you look into threading.Timer as recursive and set timer as you wish and call the function at program start there you can either update the file name in array/dict so that it will be reflected to rest of program or you can write the contents of the array into file and empty the array.

```
     def write_it():
        threading.Timer(300, write_it).start()

     write_it()
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. In my code the problem is i am getting time variation. The code is to store values in a txt file but it takes 1-2 second to store the values and because of that i  am not getting the exact time frames. So i am thinking of to store the values first in array and then to a  file. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it using RotatingFileHandler which is a python logging class. Our scope changed from 5 second to one hour so what i did i ran the program for 1 hour and the i got a file which was of 135 mb and this i converted to bytes and used those bytes in the maxBytes argument. So what happens now in this code is that once the file size reaches to bytes mentioned in the code it creates another file and starts storing the values in it and it continues doing same for 5 files. i hope this helps to other people having similar kind of usecase.

```
logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  handler = RotatingFileHandler('/home/pi/VibrationSensor/test.txt', maxBytes=20, backupCount=5)
  logger.addHandler(handler)

  while True:
    ti = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000)
    x, y, z = lis3dh.acceleration
    logger.info('{}, {}, {}, {}'.format(ti,x / 9.806, y / 9.806, z / 9.806))
    time.sleep(0.001)
    pass
```